# Matrix creation with indexed assignment: what is the logic when the dimensions don't match?

Tags: matlab, matrix, assign, submatrix

I am puzzled by the following:

```
A(1,:) = zeros(1,1,5); % 1x5
A(1,:) = zeros(1,1,1,5); % 1x5
A(1,:) = zeros(1,1,1,1,5); % 1x5
```

The leading singleton dimensions get ignored.

```
A(:,1) = zeros(1,1,5); % 5x1
A(:,1) = zeros(1,1,1,5); % 5x1
A(:,1) = zeros(1,1,1,1,5); % 5x1
```

Now there seems to be a transposition on top of the dimensions being ignored.

```
A(1,:,:) = zeros(1,1,5); % 1x5
A(1,:,:,:) = zeros(1,1,5); % 1x1x1x5
A(1,:,:,:,:) = zeros(1,1,5); % 1x5
```

The trailing colons seem to get ignored until the left-hand side asks for 1 more dimension than the right-hand side.

```
A(:,:,1) = zeros(1,1,5); % 5x1
A(:,:,:,1) = zeros(1,1,5); % 1x1x5
A(:,:,:,:,1) = zeros(1,1,5); % 5x1
```

The leading colons seem to get ignored until the same situation presents itself.

I do see a pattern, but I am confused and I am not sure I could anticipate the behaviour of more complex code. What is the logic behind this?